# Is there a way to run in parallel completeley unrelated tasks in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing

In other words, since I am mostly used to C# - there you can use Parallel.Invoke for structured parallelism and run 2 or more completely unrelated classes almost at the same time, such as:

```
public void hello_world()
{
    //hello world code
}

public void mysql_connect()
{
    //connect to mysql here
}

/// Now run them both at the same time

Parallel.Invoke(hello_world, mysal_connect);
```

It's very simple and completely parallel. I read in C/C++ you can use OMP but this seems to be about parent that runs in parallel children with the same logic but different variables, not?

Comment: Do you want a C or C++ answer, with modern C++ the answers will be completely different.  What have you looked at so far (there are whole books on this subject)?  This question (without some clarification) is very close to too broad.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Whichever works. Preferably C though. Right now I am looking at this: https://randu.org/tutorials/threads/ . I managed to write some C code which uses CURL to do plenty of things but can't parallelize it. That is...downloading logs from 3 of my servers doesn'tt run at nearly the same time. Again, I managed to do it in C# as mentioned above.

Comment: C/C++ doesn' exist.

Comment: When using curl, you might skip C/++ and use a simple shell script.

Comment: @JohnyLeo For C you either want to use Native OS threading support or pthread.  How to use pthread is too broad for SO and has books on the subject.

Comment: classes dont run. methods do and instances can, but classes are just abstract entities. It is not 100% clear what you want to do. Maybe start by fixing the code. `public void hello_world()` is not valid syntax

Comment: @OlafDietsche: I know/hope so...but it's not just CURL, I have to do plenty of things such as connectiong to MySQL, regular expressions (that seem to slow it...), etc. etc. ,so I am looking at the best way to parallelize.

Comment: @RichardCritten:Yes, it seems so...there is probably something wrong in my implementation of pthreads, but it seems as OMP/MPI isn't the answer.

Comment: When you have unrelated tasks, there's no need for threads. Keep it simple and use multiple processes, e.g. use `fork`.

Comment: Olaf Dietsche: Thanks, I read about it now, this seems to be taking it another step further as fork() launches processes/other programs? In this case I sitll may use it, will try now fork() + the OMP task method as Genis suggested.

Comment: @JohnyLeo C++ has `std::thread`, while C - doesn't. Pick tags according to what answer you want. There's no such language as C/C++.

Comment: Flagging as unclear since you can't pick a language that you want to work with.

Comment: That's a lot of downvoting to foist on a new user. I'm upvoting: asking good questions is a learned skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with OpenMP tasks. Open a parallel block and create two task blocks in it. Something like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{

   #pragma omp task {
      // hello world code 
   }
   #pragma omp task {
      // connect mysql
   }
}
```

Add the `-fopenmp` option to your compilation line. There might be better approaches than that, as it requires you putting all the code in the same code block. Anyway that's quite an easy solution with minimal code addition.

Comment: Thanks, I will try now, hopefully the omp task will run in parallel even in the case of for loops. I am also testing the C code on virtual machine (Ubuntu), not sure how this relates to the CPU.